# Create an error with native or unknown stack frame location

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, v8

According to the [V8 Stack Trace API](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Stack-Trace-API), there are errors with native or unknown location. Is it possible to produce these errors with vanilla js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an error at `native` with Vanilla JS like so:

```
> try { String.fromCodePoint(-42); } catch(e) { console.log(e.stack);}
RangeError: Invalid code point -42
    at Function.fromCodePoint (native)
    at <anonymous>:1:14
```

In V8, some functions are implemented in JS. For example, String.fromCodePoint was here https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/5.2-lkgr/src/js/string.js#L784. Other functions are implemented in C++. I believe, if the error is thrown in a JS function, it's native. If the function is implemented in C++, the error is not at `native.` Here's an error from `encodeURI`, which is implemented in C++ (https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/uri.cc#L180).

```
> try { encodeURI('\uDFFF'); } catch(e) { console.log(e.stack);}
URIError: URI malformed
    at <anonymous>:1:7
```

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! Is there a way to generate error with `at ... (unkown location)`? It does not have to be vanilla js, just for curiosity...

Answer (score 0):

This is a long topic, but v8 is written in c++ and stacks are maintained in c++ and given to javascript when a new error is thrown from c++. but you can send your own customized errors as follows:

## 1: Capture error stack:

To get the stack of an error you access it by accessing its `.stack` property.

for example:

```
fs.readFile('./Index.html', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
    }
});
```

## 2: Sending your own custom stack (any text basically)

Stack property is added on the objects like any property which enables you to do the following:

```
function trace() {
  try {
    var err = new Error('myError');
    err.stack = "custom written stack!";
    throw err;
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
  }
}
```

## 3: Using captureStackTrace to log proper custom stacks

`Error.captureStackTrace(targetObject[, constructorOpt])`

> Creates a .stack property on targetObject, which when accessed returns
>   a string representing the location in the code at which
>   Error.captureStackTrace() was called.

```
function MyError() {
  Error.captureStackTrace(this, MyError);
}

// Without passing MyError to captureStackTrace, the MyError
// frame would show up in the .stack property. By passing
// the constructor, we omit that frame and all frames above it.
new MyError().stack
```

### capturing stacks of throw new Errors

To capture the stack of the new thrown error you can write the following:

```
function trace() {
  try {
    throw new Error('myError');
  }
  catch(e) {
    alert(e.stack);
  }
}
function b() {
  trace();
}
```

calling b will log the following:

```
Error: myError
    at trace (<anonymous>:3:15)
    at b (<anonymous>:10:7)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Vanilla js means, you cannot use node.js modules, like fs, it should work e.g. in Chrome as well. I am looking for an error, which has `at ... (unkown location)` or `at ... (native)` in the stack trace. According to the v8 documentation there should be such errors.